# Connection with FireBase (RealTimeData) doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I followed a tutorial, to transmit data between RealTime Database and an Android application.
But when I launch the application here are my LogCat :

As you can see, I have an error with an API, but also with the server location, which I moved from Belgium to the North of the United States (on Firebase).

```
2021-08-22 16:02:18.136 26604-30773/com.example.scanmagic D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=85
2021-08-22 16:02:18.137 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d07a0ba[MainActivity]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.137 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
2021-08-22 16:02:18.137 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.scanmagic ic=null mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2021-08-22 16:02:18.137 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2021-08-22 16:02:18.141 26604-30801/com.example.scanmagic W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [400 Bad Request: {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
            "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
            "domain": "googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
              "service": "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.141 26604-30801/com.example.scanmagic W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyB6jO1IHuckLg4QmQEzhzKIHaM9V-t9dxA, magic-scan-9441b, 1:564949178912:android:339b1576cd72d9987fba45
2021-08-22 16:02:18.141 26604-30801/com.example.scanmagic E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2021-08-22 16:02:18.157 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic D/SurfaceControl: hide : mNativeObject = 512954323936 - sc.mNativeObject = 515630356992 - Surface(name=Surface(name=b17cbe9 InputMethod)/@0x95b6f9c - animation-leash)/@0x77087e
2021-08-22 16:02:18.157 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic D/SurfaceControl: nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=b17cbe9 InputMethod)/@0x95b6f9c - animation-leash)/@0x77087e
2021-08-22 16:02:18.159 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: release : mNativeObject = 515630352960 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6fa40ef NavigationBar0)/@0xd0c2b27 - animation-leash)/@0x6b931df / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
2021-08-22 16:02:18.159 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[515630352960]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.159 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[515630352960]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.160 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: release : mNativeObject = 515630354016 - Surface(name=Surface(name=5b2d6db StatusBar)/@0xd23cb28 - animation-leash)/@0xb865e2c / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
2021-08-22 16:02:18.160 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[515630354016]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.160 26604-26604/com.example.scanmagic I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[515630354016]
2021-08-22 16:02:18.517 26604-30807/com.example.scanmagic W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://magic-scan-9441b-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
2021-08-22 16:02:23.224 26604-30796/com.example.scanmagic V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code with reference to this. So let me tell you the possible ways you could fix this. Since you told you were following a tutorial, the google API version they are using might be outdated. Check your build.gradle file and update the dependency if necessary.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Another solution is to check if the API key in your google-services.json file matches your API key from firebase. Either way just delete and paste the file again and then build your app.

Comment: Better to wait until the OP has posted code before you suggest solutions.

Comment: umm yeah you're right. I just assumed the most probable issue and gave a solution.